# VM Agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from Running

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a VM using a managed data disk but there is a problem of VMAgent for connecting through ssh. 
Command is:

```
az vm create --resource-group Test_Group --location eastus --name myVM2 --os-type linux --attach-os-disk disk1
```

The error is:

> VM Agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from Running.

If I try to install a new VMAgent it throws an error of MultipleVMAgents not allowed and current enablevmaccess extension shows status(unavailable).

Comment: You say "I created a VM using a managed data disk" but the command you are using shows --attach-os-disk which is for operating system disks (e.g. if you migrate an om-prem VM to Azure). So what is it that you want to do? Create a new VM based on a standard image (and then attach a data disk), or create an Azure VM running an OS image that you have already uploaded to Azure Storage?

Comment: Basically the data disk has all operating system data which i transferred in it manually but it is a data disk. So created a VM using the above command and that data disk.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have had luck in situations like this with just redeploying the VM through the Azure Portal: When you click on your linux VM in the portal you have a menu item on the left called "Redeploy" (almost at the bottom)

Comment: I will try it but i am not so sure it will work.

Comment: @rasmusgude I made a redeploy but the still can't connect to my VM, and I get the same warning saying "VM Agent is either unavailable, or not installed, which may prevent VMAccess from Running.".

Comment: At last resource, you can try these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-local-password-without-agent

Comment: See if this works out for you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/846938/azure-rm-vm-the-vm-agent-is-either-unavailable-or-not-installed-which-may-pr